# Can i upload videos on mobile safari?

Tags: mobile-safari, websites

i am working on a asp.net web app.This app is mainly related with media in which user have to upload images and videos.It works fine on other browsers rather than mobile safari.

I had solved one problem here by using picup app but now problem is how i can upload videos here

thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is more a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @Ermiar i think this is the limitation of mobile safari thats why i posted it here.

Comment: But it already has been answered on StackOverflow :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891831/a-html5-web-app-for-mobile-safari-to-upload-images-from-the-photos-app

Comment: @Gerry yes you are right i already checked this one also.It means we require to use third party component to solve this problem ?

Comment: You'd need a native app for any upload functionality.